# Laravel ElFinder with S3 drive generating but not uploading thumbnails

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, elfinder

I'm using Laravel with ElFinder on Heroku and to prevent my files being erased daily I'm moving them onto an S3 bucket.

Everything is working fine with the exception of the thumbnails. These are still being generated on the local disk (public/.tmb) and hence they're being deleted every night. I've manually uploaded the thumbnails to the directory on S3 and then everything is perfect. I just need this step to be done automatically.

Does anyone know what I need to change to get the thumbnails uploaded into the bucket.

**ElFinder.php**

```
'disks' => [
    's3' => [
        'URL'=> 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx/',
        'tmbURL'=> 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx/.tmb'
    ]
],

'root_options' => array(
    'imgLib'     => 'gd',
    'tmbPath'    => '.tmb',
    'tmbCrop'    => false,
    'attributes' => array(
        array(
            'pattern' => '/\/\./',
            'read' => false,
            'write' => false,
            'locked' => true,
            'hidden' => true
        )
    )
),
```

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "ext-gd": "*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-elfinder": "^0.3.11",
    "baum/baum": "^1.1",
    "bestmomo/laravel-email-confirmation": "^1.0",
    "bestmomo/laravel5-artisan-language": "^0.1.2",
    "creativeorange/gravatar": "^1.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "intervention/image": "^2.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0"
},
```

Comment: There are multiple similar issues opened at their GitHub page, this guy seems to solve part of the issue https://github.com/barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driver/issues/60 maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thanks @veNuker that got me started. I was trying to do it without using Glide as I'd seen issue with that approach. In the end I fixed the ElFinder bug which was stopping glide from working.

Comment: Glad I could help:)